# Facelet client does not use assigned facelet client

Tags: jsf

Hope you can help me with this trivial problem. I have created a facelet template like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/default.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/cssLayout.css"/>
        <title>Facelets Template</title>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>

            <div id="top">
                <ui:insert name="top"><h1>Super Cool App</h1></ui:insert>
            </div>

            <div id="content" class="center_content">
                <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
            </div>

            <div id="bottom">
                <ui:insert name="bottom"><br/><br/>Powered by GlassFish & NetBeans</ui:insert>
            </div>

        </h:body>

    </html>
```

Now I have a facelet client which is assigned to the template like below. However, when I remove the top and bottom part of the clients facelet, it should inherence the top and bottom stuff from the template, right? But it does not. Could you tell me, what I did wrong?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="content">
                content
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance. See you along.

Comment: What are the symptoms? What *does* show up that you don't expect? What shows up that you don't expect?

Comment: It just displays "content" from the client. I expected that, since there is no top and bottom defined in the client, it will use the top and bottom of the template. Which should display: "Super cool app!" as Top and "Powered by GlassFish & NetBeans" as Bottom.